# Android Navigation Drawer Menu Item Not able to high light Selected Item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

First item is highlighted and rest is not able to high light:

Here is my bg selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/accent_translucent" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

I tried

1. `onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));`
2. `onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_profile));`
3. `navigationView.setCheckedItem(id);`

Nothing Seems Working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_main"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/dashboard"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_profile"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/profile"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_third"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/leaderboard"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_fourt"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_horiz_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/notification"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_fifth"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/logout"/>

</group>
```

```
 navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            int id = menuItem.getItemId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.drawer_dashboard:
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
case R.id.drawer_profile:
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
```

Any ideas will be helpful

if i use below code i can highlight but unable to start new activity

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return true;
```

Comment: No idea, why you are calling this line - onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_dashboard));

Comment: i tried ithat code  from stack ..Rest of code belongs to me

Comment: i have updated the code..Can u pls check out now

Answer (score 1):

When the view is created, please try to use getItem(int index) method to get all the MenuItem, and then call setCheckable(true), make sure it is can be checkable.

Answer (score 0):

Android allows very limited access of menu items. The best way to highlight a menu item is to use a faded icon in menu, and if you want to highlight just replace the icon with more colourful icons.

```
 navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_dashboard‌).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_highlighted_icon);
```

and for rest reset the normal icons.

Additionally, try your old code -

```
onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(id));
navigationView.setCheckedItem(id);
```

Here replace id by current item position.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Updated my answer, kindly check :)

Comment: am getting error index out of exception...i didnt declare array.is it bcoz of that